# Monitoring MongoDB queries

Tags: database, mongodb, performance, monitoring, database-administration

Oracle has a pretty cool "Database Grid control" where it's easy to see what's impacting the server, what client is having too many connections, who is running what queries, who is taking memory in queries and who is taking cpu in queries.

I suspect all the data is in there, between mongostat, mongotop, currentQueries, slow logs etc.
But I am looking for a nice UI package that aggregates that and always for high level applicational monitoring.

Is there anything like that out there?

Answer (score 0):

Mongo 4 introduced free cloud monitoring:

https://www.mongodb.com/blog/post/introducing-free-cloud-monitoring-for-mongodb

Comment: Thank you, however: 1) The cloud monitoring is extremely basic and is even less than what I get from basic grafana connectors, mainly it's focus is on the health of the servers, and less on the load from clients (which could be hundreds of machines and services)
2) In many companies, you can’t have real data on the cloud in the granularity needed (name of host that is impacting the server, process Ids, specific query and index patterns), the risk is too high.